# How to access DOM elements through jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to performance profiling, and i want to find request per sec. 
First i have used ab tool **ab -n 1 -c 1 http://www.xxxxx.com/** but the total transferred bytes is very less when compared to the size when page gets loaded. Now I am using jmeter, and even in this also the bytes is less. The reason is because the images which my page contains are taken from s3 and they are not included in jmeter. I came to know that we have to write a script to include these dom elements. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab and ensure you have the following boxes ticked:

   - Retrieve All Embedded Resources
   - Parallel Downloads

     [image: HTTP Request Defaults JMeter]

This will enable JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to hit images, scripts and styles which are referenced in the "parent" HTML page behaving like a real browser. See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more detailed explanation of above tip and few more recommendations on making your JMeter test more realistic.

Comment: I have already checked those two boxes and it also gives less number of bytes. Can you please let me know the script that should be written to include dom elements.

Comment: Less number of bytes than what? Be aware that JMeter is not a browser and it doesn't execute client-side JavaScript in the response pages, if your application is using AJAX - you need to add these requests manually (or record them using [JMeter's Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for details on how to handle AJAX in JMeter tests.

Comment: It is less than the size when page loads. My page uses angularjs and has images whose sources are in s3.